# Avogadro Molecule Editor: How to render image from command line?

Tags: computational-chemistry, software

Given a molecular geometry in the .xyz file format, how can I use Avogadro on the command line to render an image of it?

The website states that there is some command line API available, but I can't seem to find any documentation/information about it. Alternatively, are there any other molecular visualization tools that provide a convenient command line interface for image rendering of .xyz files?

Comment: Pymol does a pretty good job and you can do everything using the command line. There's also a lot of documentation on it.

Comment: @DSVA Thanks for pointing that out ; ) I think I will go into that direction for now. Do you know if pymol can also directly render to png without starting the UI?

Comment: Yes, you can start it in command line mode (https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Command_Line_Options) or use API and the command you are looking for is "png" https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Png

Comment: That's awesome. I really needed that functionality for a presentation on thursday. I somehow have *a lot* of geometries to analyze, so I needed some kind of access to rendering geometries from python. I think that really is what I was searching for : ) You made my day, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to currently do this using Avogadro, although Python bindings have been "in the works" for a while. The problem is, with volunteer developers, there's not always enough free time to tackle all features.

You can create pseudo-3D images using Open Babel. I developed this for the [Pitt Quantum Repository](http://pqr.pitt.edu/) to give SVG and PNG images in the search interface. It's not perfect, but I like the effect.

```
obabel beta-carotene.xyz -O beta-carotene-2d.svg -xS -xd -xb none
```

[image]

The `-xS` indicates this 3D "ball and stick" style, `-xd` prevents the molecule name from being included, and `-xb none` gives  transparent background to the SVG (useful for presentations).

Comment: This current rendering is available in the development version of Open Babel - a slightly different version is available in 2.4.x. The new "tweaks" add some scaling to atom sizes and opacity to give a depth effect, which works well in most molecules. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I really think that *convenient* solutions for batch job visualizations of molecules (e.g. md trajectories) are lacking. The only solution I found so far is pymol, which however I quite dislike due to their licensing choice (e.g. real 3d rendering lacking in free version and so on). So this is quite interesting...

Comment: Agreed on the need for convenient solutions for batch visualization. I was hopeful that we'd have Python bindings for Avogadro2 by now, but the student tackling that last year in Google Summer of Code disappeared (likely doing some other research).

Comment: @deusexmachina You may be able to script VMD to do this -- Geoff, thoughts? It's Tcl/Tk driven, right?

Comment: @hBy2Py - that's likely true, although I can't find any documentation on running VMD as a command-line tool.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison What is meant by python bindings. Sorry if this is an amateur question. I am very new to python, but we use OpenBabel frequently.

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is a simple 2D structure, [OpenBabel can do it for you](https://openbabel.org/docs/dev/FileFormats/PNG_2D_depiction.html).
Say you have a structure named `beta-carotene.xyz`:

[image: beta-carotene.xyz]

The following command issues a 2D depiction of the above:

```
$ obabel beta-carotene.xyz -O beta-carotene-2d.png -xp 600 -x0 molfile
```

[image: beta-carotene-2d.png]

Comment: Its about 3D structures.